# NServiceBus ignore auditing specific message type

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

I have a NSB endpoint which polls a database every 'n' minutes to send some data to other end points. I am using the built-in scheduler. It is recommended to just do 'Bus.SendLocal' in the scheduler code and have a handler call the database. The scheduler just queues a message whenever it wakes up and the handler handles it like any other message. Looks cleaner and all works fine.

Issue which I'm running into:
ServiceInsight captures all the messages and its now filled with too many wake-up messages, one every 'n' mins.

Question:
Is there a way to turn-off auditing a specific message type or any other recommended solution?

Answer (score 3):

Currently NServiceBus does not support this feature.

If you would like this feature please raise an issue here https://github.com/Particular/nservicebus/issues

Comment: Actually the issue would be better suited for ServiceInsight repo at https://github.com/Particular/ServiceInsight/issues/new, since the request is really to filter out displayed messages in ServiceInsight